# feedback on solution to Rudin Chapter 2 Exercise 2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image: the problem in question]

Does my reasoning check out? Am I missing any nontrivial steps? Understandable exposition? Thank you so much in advance.

Edit, typed it in mathjax:

Let $z=(x_1,x_2)$ and consider the expression for $n=1$:

$a_0z+a_1=0$ => $(a_0x_1+a_1, a_0x_2)=(0,0)$ => $x_1=-a_1/a_0$ and $x_2=0$.

The set (call it A) containing all values of $x_1$ satisfying the expression is therefore an infinite subset of Q, and thus countable. A is equivalent to the set $Z_1$ containing all z which are solutions to the expression, therefore $Z_1$ is countable.

Assuming $Z_k$ is countable for arbitrary k, consider $Z_{k+1}$:

Define the bijective function $$f:Z_k->Z_0$$ with $$f(z)=z^2$$ Notice that $Z_0 \bigcap Z_1=Z_{k+1}$.The intersection of these two countable sets must be countable, completing induction.

Comment: This is not a solution to the stated problem.

Comment: Please use Mathjax.

Comment: The  photo, as usually the case, is too bothersome to read because of glare, being a rough first draft ,  and other problems..

Comment: I edited in my proof with mathjax.

Comment: Your solution is hard to follow. Assuming what you call $A$ is the set of algebraic numbers and $Z_1$ is the set of complex numbers $z$ for which there are $(a_1,a_0) \in \Bbb Z^2\setminus(0,0)$ with $a_1z+a_0 = 0$, these sets are *not* equal (or 'equivalent'). $Z_1$ would be a subset of $A$. You did not define $Z_k$ or $Z_0$. In light of this, the rest of your proof doesn't make much sense for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I meant that $A=\{x_1 : x_1=-a_1/a_0\}$ where $a_1$ and $a_0$ are any integers. Then by equivalent I mean there exists a bijection from A to $Z_1$ that just puts $x_1$ into $(x_1, 0)$. $Z_k$ is meant to be the set of solutions to the expression in the problem when we put $n=k$ for some arbitrary k.  $Z_0$ was just a placeholder for the image when you plug in $z^2$ for z so I didn't think I had to define it.

Comment: I think I understand what you wanted to say now. You wanted to show that each $Z_k$ is countable, using induction. $(1)$ That's fine, but then what? You need to show that the set of algebraic numbers is countable. $(2)$ Okay, you showed that $Z_1$ is countable (you could be a bit more clear here, but we can see that), which is the base case for the induction. Now I suppose you wanted to do the inductive step, something like "Suppose that for some $k$ $Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_k$ are countable. We will show that $Z_{k+1}$ is also countable". After this, your proof falls apart.

Comment: Notice for instance that you claim that any $z\in Z_{k+1}$ (for any $k$!) would be an element of $Z_1$, which is a subset of $\Bbb Q$. But we have that $\pm\sqrt2$, the solutions to $z^2-2 = 0$, are elements of $Z_2$. I would recommend you reconsider your approach to the inductive step, and generally try and be more clear to the reader at each step about what you doing and where you intend to get.

Comment: yeah thanks for helping me realize what was (horribly and obviously lol) wrong. I think my approach CAN work but it is just way harder to find the inductive step than it is to solve this with the method given in the hint. I'm going to move on, as I've solved it with the method given by William, but maybe I'll come back to it later after I've tackled the other exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an n-th degree polynomial there are at most most n different solutions.
There are only countablely many n-th degree polynomials with integer coefficients.  (Proof to be provided by reader.)
So for each n in N, there are countablely many algebraic numbers.
That is what hint is pointing out.
Now add together the number of algebraic numbers for all those n's.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like he assumes the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is known. I typed out my proposed solution in my latest edit if you could let me know what you think.

Comment: @CadeBruce. We do not need the Fund. Thm. of Algebra for this Q. By elementary means, an $n$th degree polynomial  equation over $\Bbb C$ has at most  $n$  solutions. For this Q it wouldn't matter if "at most $n$" could sometimes be  $0$.