# Clarification on Baby Rudin Chapter 2 Exercise 2

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

I have a basic question about Baby Rudin Chapter 2 Exercise 2. There are a number of solutions online and on StackExchange, but I'm still left with some questions.

> A complex number $z$ is said to be *algebraic* if there are integers $a_0, \ldots a_n$, not all zero, such that $$a_0 z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + \ldots a_{n-1}z + a_n = 0.$$ Prove that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable. *Hint*: For every positive integer $N$ there are only finitely many equations with $$n + |a_0| + |a_1| + \ldots + |a_n| = N.$$

Some [solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306130/feedback-on-solution-to-rudin-chapter-2-exercise-2) note that (i) polynomials of degree $n$ have at most $n$ different solutions, and (ii) since there are countably many $n$-th degree polynomials with integer coefficients, the set of algebraic numbers is a union of countable sets and hence it is countable.

- Is Rudin's hint meant to help us prove (i) or (ii)?
- Is the following proof for (ii) correct?

> Fix $z$. Map the polynomial $a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + a_n = 0$ to the list $(n, a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. The set of lists $\{(n, a_0, \ldots, a_n): n\in \mathbb{N}, a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}, \ldots a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is countable, since the Cartesian product of a finite $n$-tuple of integers $(a_0, \ldots, a_n)$ is [countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205125/is-the-set-of-ordered-tuples-of-integers-countable) and the Cartesian product of the two countable sets $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable. Hence, for each $z$, the set of polynomials with integer coefficients is at-most countable.

- I can find proofs for (i) online, but would anyone mind showing me how Rudin's hint can be used to prove (i)? Or (ii), if that's what the hint is for?

Comment: I think his hint is to avoid the mistake (which I've made many times) that if there are a countable number of each coefficient we can map a polynomial to the ordered $n$-tuple of its coefficients.  Thus we have a mapping of polynomials to the countable cartesian product $\mathbb Z^{|\mathbb N|}$. This is an error as a countable cross products of countable sets is *NOT* countable.  This is fixable as all polynomials is a *finite* $n$-tuple and none require the "full" infinite cross product to contain it. Unfortunately no finite crossproduct will work. Rudin's hint allows us a way to set it up.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood. So, is the problem that Rudin says they are a finite number of *equations* satisfying $n = |a_0| + |a_1| + \ldots + |a_n|$ and not a finite number of coefficients? Given $N$ and $n$, I assumed that for each equation, there could only be finite number of integer coefficient combinations where (i) only $n+1$ of them were non-zero; (ii) their squared sums came to $N-n$. But, I don't know why I assumed that ...

Comment: I (and I imagine over 90% of all students) thought we could map a polynomial to $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}....+a_0\to (a_n,a_{n-1},...,a_0)\in \mathbb Z^{somevalue}$ There are countably many so... but this is wrong because in order to capture *all* possible polynomials we need $\mathbb Z^{\aleph_0}$ which is uncountable.  But as we do not include any infinite polynomials this isn't an error. But we are back to square one.  Rudin avoids this but taking unions and not cross products. (A subtle difference)...

Comment: Rudin instead comes up with another we of sorting the polynomials.  If you take any polynomial and add up the absolute value of the coefficients and add to that it's power you always get a natural number.  We can classify all polynomials so that each polynomial goes into exactly *one* of these classes.  Then... as the classes are *finite* (the hint) we have classified the number of polynomials into a countable union of finite sets. And as each polynomial has finite number of roots. Countable alg numbers. TA-DA.

Comment: P(1) will include the polynomials $\pm 1, \pm x$.$P(2)$ will include $\pm 2, \pm x\pm 1, \pm x^2$,  $P(3)$ will include the polynomials $\pm 3, \pm x\pm 2,\pm x^2\pm 1,\pm x^2\pm x, \pm x^3$ And so an all polynomials are cover by these (example $x^5 + 7x^4 -23x^2 + 7 \in P(43))$... I *think* but I may be jumping the gun that each $P(n)$ will have $2^n$  polynomials.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks! This is interesting. I relied so much on his hint that I didn't think of doing that. (Or did I, in the answer I posted at the very bottom of this page? In that case, I need to fix it). So, Rudin prevents the reader from falling in the trap of assuming that we can enumerate all polynomials with integer coefficients. (Also, above, did you mean to write "so that each goes into exactly one" or "so that each goes into at least one"?)

Comment: @fleablood Also, is the reason that we can enumerate rational numbers (product of two countable sets) and not polynomials is because, to say that we've included a single polynomial in our set, we must enumerate an infinite chain of coefficients, whereas for a rational we only need the numerator/denominator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of proving that, for each $N\in\Bbb Z_+$, there are only finitely many polynomials $a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}z+a_n$, with $n=|a_0|+|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|=N$ is that then the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients is countable, since it is a countable union of finite sets. Since each such polynomial, other than the null polynomial, has only finitely many roots, it follows that there are only countably many algebraic numbers.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems Rudin's hint is meant to help us prove (ii) and he assumes that the reader already knows (i)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few answers out there for this question, but as a beginner, I had a hard time understanding many of them. Here's my approach, which may be overly simple/wordy but (if correct) could help beginners searching for a more "obvious" answer.

Recall that an algebraic number $z \in Z$ satisfies
$$a_0 z^n + a_1 z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_n = 0$$
where $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are all integers.

**The set $Z$ is infinite**: when $n = 1$, algebraic numbers are those satisfying $a_1 z + a_0 = 0$ or $z = -a_1/a_0$. So rational numbers are a subset of algebraic numbers, and since rational numbers are infinite, so are algebraic numbers.

**$Z$ is at most countable** We use Rudin's hint that, for any natural number $N$, there are only finitely many equations with

$$N = n + |a_0| + |a_1| + \ldots + |a_n|$$

For each $N$, we have a set of coefficients satisfying the equation above. We can associate each of these with an expression. In the table below, I've considered the case where $N = 5$ and listed *just some* of the coefficients satisfying the equation above, associated expressions, and the values $z$ where the expressions equal zero.

| $n$ | $a_0$ | $a_1$ | $a_2$ | $a_3$ | $a_4$ | Expression | Zeros |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | $z^4$ | $z=0$ |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | $z^3 + 1$ | $z = -1$ |
| 2 | 1 | -2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | $z^2 - 2z$ | $z =2$ or $z = 0$ |

- Let $A_N$ be the set of expressions associated with $N$ (e.g., $A_5$ includes the expressions $z^4$ and $z^3 + 1$ among others). Rudin tells us this set is finite. (See edit at end).
- The number of roots associated with each expression in $A_N$ is also finite, so the roots represented by the expressions in each $A_N$ are also finite. I'll call the set of roots $B_N$.

Most answers say that Rudin assumes we know that polynomials of degree $n$ have, at most, $n$ roots. But, I think we just need to be convinced that each polynomial has a finite number of roots.

- Since $N$ is countable and each $B_N$ is finite, the union $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty B_N$ is countable. The set of algebraic numbers is only a subset of this union, since some roots are repeated (e.g., $z = 0$ in the first and third rows of the table). So, the algebraic numbers are at most countable.

Since the algebraic numbers are infinite and at-most countable, they are countable.

Edit: As @fleablood commented to my initial question, Rudin's hint prevents the reader from making *incorrect* argument that the set of polynomials is countable, since we can enumerate the coefficients (in the countable set $\mathbb{Z}$) and their degrees (in the countable set $\mathbb{N}$).